# Java library that has parseInt, parseLong, parseDouble, etc that accept default values and don't throw exceptions?

Tags: java, parsing

I like the suggestion in [String to Int in java - Likely bad data, need to avoid exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/174502/string-to-int-in-java-likely-bad-data-need-to-avoid-exceptions) to implement a utility method that parses an int, but returns a default value if the string cannot be parsed.

```
public static int parseInt(String s, int defaultValue) {
    if (s == null) return defaultValue;
    try {
         return Integer.parseInt(s);
     } catch (NumberFormatException x) {
         return defaultValue;
     }  
}
```

Is there an existing open source library (from apache commons, or google, for example) that implements this as well as for other data types such as boolean, float, double, long, etc?

Comment: `default` is a reserved word. Also, it's probably easier to code this yourself.

Comment: Changed the example not to use a reserved word.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[Apache Commons Lang](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/) has the class [`org.apache.commons.lang3.math.NumberUtils`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang//apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/math/NumberUtils.html) with convenient methods for convert. In another way, you can specify a default value if there is a error. e.g.

```
NumberUtils.toLong("")         => 0L
NumberUtils.toLong(null, 1L)   => 1L

NumberUtils.toByte(null)       => 0
NumberUtils.toByte("1", 0)     => 1
```

Comment: Although it does parse without exception, the default value might be undesirable.
If that is your case like mine there is the org.apache.commons.validator.routines.LongValidator.validate(String) can also take a pattern and/or Locale.

Answer (score 7):

[Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) has several `tryParse` methods that return null on a failed parse, e.g. [Ints.tryParse](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v11.0.1/javadoc/com/google/common/primitives/Ints.html#tryParse%28java.lang.String%29), [Floats.tryParse](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/primitives/Floats.html#tryParse%28java.lang.String%29), etc

Comment: While these methods don't throw NumberFormatException, it should be noted that if you pass a null String into them, they will throw a NullPointerException rather than just returning null.