# Handling exceptions with streams

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a `Map<String,List<String>>` and want it to turn into `Map<String,List<Long>>` because each `String` in the list represents a `Long` :

```
Map<String,List<String>> input = ...;
Map<String,List<Long>> output= 
input.entrySet()
       .stream()
       .collect(toMap(Entry::getKey, e -> e.getValue().stream()
                                                      .map(Long::valueOf)
                                                      .collect(toList()))
               );
```

My main issue is each `String` may not represent correctly a `Long`; there may be some issue. `Long::valueOf` may raise exceptions. If this is the case, I want to return a null or empty `Map<String,List<Long>>`

Because I want to iterate after over this `output` map. But I cannot accept any error conversion; not even a single one. Any idea as to how I can return an empty output in case of incorrect  String -> Long conversion?

Comment: I agree with Naman solution but unfortunately in the catch block, I fail to retrieve the key (Entry::getKey) for which the String -> Long conversion is incorrect

Comment: Similar discussion here: [String to int - likely bad data need to avoid exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/174502/string-to-int-in-java-likely-bad-data-need-to-avoid-exceptions/45028739#45028739) where I eventually decided to pre-check with regex (parseLong docs use the same parsing rules & you probably want to return a `LongStream` if you plan to remove `empty` results)

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood. I thought you meant to return a single entry as empty/null; but now I think you mean the entire Map!

Comment: It's not entirely clear what the main point is - you want to return an empty map in case of an error, but still print the "key" where the error appeared to the console? I mean, information about the context where the exception appeared is usually transported up the call stack *in* the exception. Regardless of that: You specifically asked about streams, but I'd **strongly** recommend to avoid nested "collect" calls. People who have to maintain that later (and this may well be *future you*!) will wonder what the h... you did there. At least introduce some properly named helper methods.

Answer (score 5):

I personally like to provide an `Optional` input around number parsing:

```
public static Optional<Long> parseLong(String input) {
    try {
        return Optional.of(Long.parseLong(input));
    } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
        return Optional.empty();
    }
}
```

Then, using your own code (and *ignoring* bad input):

```
Map<String,List<String>> input = ...;
Map<String,List<Long>> output= 
input.entrySet()
       .stream()
       .collect(toMap(Entry::getKey, e -> e.getValue().stream()
                                                      .map(MyClass::parseLong)
                                                      .filter(Optional::isPresent)
                                                      .map(Optional::get)
                                                      .collect(toList()))
               );
```

Additionally, consider a helper method to make this more succinct:

```
public static List<Long> convertList(List<String> input) {
    return input.stream()
        .map(MyClass::parseLong).filter(Optional::isPresent).map(Optional::get)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}

public static List<Long> convertEntry(Map.Entry<String, List<String>> entry) {
    return MyClass.convertList(entry.getValue());
}
```

Then you can filter the results in your stream's collector:

```
Map<String, List<Long>> converted = input.entrySet().stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Entry::getKey, MyClass::convertEntry));
```

You could also keep the empty `Optional` objects in your lists, and then by comparing their index in the new `List<Optional<Long>>` (instead of `List<Long>`) with the original `List<String>`, you can find the string which caused any erroneous inputs. You could also simply log these failures in `MyClass#parseLong`

However, if your desire is to not operate on *any* bad input at all, then surrounding the entire stream in what you're attempting to catch (per Naman's answer) is the route I would take.

Answer (score 4):

How about an explicit `catch` over the exception:

```
private Map<String, List<Long>> transformInput(Map<String, List<String>> input) {
    try {
        return input.entrySet()
                .stream()
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, e -> e.getValue().stream()
                        .map(Long::valueOf)
                        .collect(Collectors.toList())));
    } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
        // log the cause
        return Collections.emptyMap();
    }
}
```

Comment: ok sounds good...but in the catch(nfe) I would like to retrieve the specific value of key (Entry::getKey) and incorrect String for which it fails so I can log precisely where it goes wrong. Is it possible ?

Comment: @AntonBoarf If you just want to log the key,  for which it failed to parse the String, use `nfe.getMessage()`

Comment: @AntonBoarf the exception’s message will contain the malformed input string. To get the responsible key, I’d do an explicit search, only when the exception happened, e.g. `input.entrySet().stream() .filter(e -> e.getValue().stream().anyMatch(s -> !new Scanner(s).hasNextLong())) .map(Map.Entry::getKey) .findAny()`

Comment: @Holder. Thanks...That seems complicated...I'm wondering if using standart for loop Java5 is not better in my case

Comment: @AntonBoarf just implement both and compare…

Answer (score 1):

You can create a `StringBuilder` for key with exception and check if `ele` is numeric as below,

```
 public static Map<String, List<Long>> transformInput(Map<String, List<String>> input) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    try {
    return input.entrySet()
            .stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, e -> e.getValue().stream()
                    .map(ele->{
                        if (!StringUtils.isNumeric(ele)) {
                            sb.append(e.getKey()); //add exception key
                            throw new NumberFormatException();
                        }
                        return Long.valueOf(ele);
                    })
                    .collect(Collectors.toList())));
} catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
    System.out.println("Exception key "+sb);
    return Collections.emptyMap();
}
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

May be you can write an helper method that can check for numeric in the string and filter them out from the stream and also null values then finally collect to the Map.

```java
// StringUtils.java
public static boolean isNumeric(String string) {
    try {
        Long.parseLong(string);
        return true;
    } catch(NumberFormatException e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

This will take care everything.

And use this in your stream.

```java
Map<String, List<Long>> newMap = map.entrySet().stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, entry -> mapToLongValues(entry.getValue())));

public List<Long> mapToLongValues(List<String> strs) {
    return strs.stream()
        .filter(Objects::nonNull)
        .filter(StringUtils::isNumeric)
        .map(Long::valueOf)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```